# Shouldn't X be less likely to happen when Y happens?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I know the rule to know if two events are independents. And if you apply the rule, here, you get that those two events are independents, however, it doesn't make sense to me that they're independent.

> A fair six-sided die is thrown twice and the scores are noted. Event X is defined as ‘The total of the
> two scores is 4’. Event Y is defined as ‘The first score is 2 or 5’. Are events X and Y independent?
> Justify your answer.

The answer is that they are independent because p(X/Y) = p(X)

But drawing a probability table we get to know that X can only happen in these cases: (3,1) or (1,3) or (2,2) [p= 3/36]

While Y happens when the first number is equal to 2 or 5

But doesn't it make sense to say that when the first number is 2 or 5 that (1,3)/(3,1)/(2,2) is **less likely** to happen. Or they are independent because of some algebraic coincidence (I've no idea if this even exists)

Comment: A dice or coin is fair if every result has the same probability no matter which results have been occured before. If this were not the case in specific real world situations, Casinos could probably not offer playing roulette , since the players could produce an edge with a suitable strategy.

Comment: @Peter There are a lot of scenarios featuring a dice where the events would happen to be dependent, take for exam event X is the probability of first number being 2 and event Y which is the probability of first number being odd. And a lot other scenarios (event A: second number is 5, event C: the sum of the numbers is 6).  This isn't a rule.

Comment: Why do you think X is less likely when Y happens? The probability of X is $1/12$ ($3$ favorable outcomes out of $36$ possibilities). The conditional probability of X given Y is also $1/12$ ($1$ favorable outcome out of $12$ possibilities).

Comment: @Andreas Blass Because under no conditions event X can happen in **three scenarios** (2,2) (1,3) (3,1) but once we apply the condition that the first number must be 2 or 5, the only scenario that's allowed to happen is only **one** (2,2) which will have the number 2 as it's first number. 
Hence, why I think event X is less likely to happen if event Y happened. Do you see where am I coming from or is my idea still not clear, if it is please tell me and I'll explain my point again.

Comment: How is **three** scenarios out of a total of $36$ more than **one** out of a total of $12$?

Comment: I know they will be simplified to be the same fraction but I wanted a rather intuitive explanation, that's mainly wordy or with-a-little-imaginary-scenario kinda explanation, more than a mathematical one. You can use numbers to proof anything but it's not a full explanation without having a sense of what's going on. Especially that the scenario we had was a very simple one, simple numbers and so. But I'm so happy you dedicated some of your time to answer me and really appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those counter-intuitive aspects of the notion of **independence** in probability: that $X$ and $Y$ are *defined* to be independent if $P(X, Y) = P(X)P(Y)$ (or other equivalent statement).

It seems odd that these two events should be independent because the result of the first die roll obviously affects whether the total is even *capable* of being $4$.  While that is indeed the case, the definition of independence does not concern itself with general causal relationships, but simply with the relationship between event probabilities and their joint probabilities.  Focusing on situations where the first roll is either $2$ or $5$ narrows the scope by a factor of $3$, which (as it so happens) is exactly the factor by which the combinations that total $4$ are narrowed.

So, for example,

- $A =$ "the first roll is $2$ or $5$"
- $B =$ "the two rolls total $5$"

are *not* independent, because the same "coincidence" does not obtain, even though the events are superficially quite similar to $X$ and $Y$ from the original problem, while

- $C =$ "the first roll is $2$, $4$, or $6$
- $D =$ "the two rolls total $5$"

*are* independent, despite the difference in form.

Comment: So you think it's more of a coincidence and that there isn't really any intuitive explanation?

Comment: @Manar: Hmm...well, I'd say it's quite intuitive in one direction: If two events are *causally* unconnected, the product rule seems reasonable.  But generalizing that to all events is, empirically, often difficult to grok.

Comment: Yeah, I really believe in the product rule and the fact that it produced counter-intuitive results here made me question my own perspective of the problem and I thought that there must be another intuitive perspective to think about it other than the one in my head and that I must had imagined the scenario somewho wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think if *does* make more sense to say that $\ \{(1,3),$$(3,1),$$(2,2)\}\ $ is less likely to happen when the first number is $2$ or $5$. You need to realise, though, that, in probability theory, the statement "given that the first number is $2$ or $5$" means that you're still completely in the dark as to *which* of those two numbers it is that has occurred, and since their prior probabilities were both $\ \frac{1}{6}\ $, then it is equally likely (i.e. with probability $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $) that the first number is a $2$, or that it is a $5$

If the first numbet is a $5$, then $\ \{(1,3),$$(3,1),$$(2,2)\}\ $ is impossible, while if it is a $2$ then the probability of $\ \{(1,3),(3,1),(2,2)\}\ $ is just the probability that the second number is a $2$—namely, $\ \frac{1}{6}\ $. So the overall probability of $\ \{(1,3),$$(3,1),$$(2,2)\}\ $ given that the first number is $2$ or $5$ is
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2}\text{ (probability first number is $2$)}\times\frac{1}{6}\\
+ &\frac{1}{2}\text{ (probability first number is $5$)}\times0\\
=&\frac{1}{12}\ ,
\end{align}
that is, the same as its prior probability given no information at all.